# setting base path in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am working on CakePHP, and I have my app working in my localhost. If I try to run my app in another machine, I need to to set the base path.

How to do this? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to set the path to the cake directory. You can do so in

```
/path/to/your/app/webroot/index.php
```

by setting the `CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH`